# media print CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working with media queries in CSS, I've not used media print before. At the button of the file where @media print is defined, is there a way to strip all formatting without having to copy all elements? I deleted most of the styling rules for brevity.

Yes this is for an assignment, my question goes beyond the scope of the class and is just form my personal knowledge.

```css
    nav.sitenavigation {
 color: yellow;
 background-color: rgb(241,90,36);
 text-align: center;
}
nav.sitenavigation p{
 display: inline-block;
 margin: .4em .6em;
 font-size: 1.6em;
}
nav.sitenavigation a:link{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: yellow;
 
}
nav.sitenavigation a:visited {
 color: white;
}
nav.sitenavigation a:hover {
 color: yellow;
 text-shadow: 1px -1px 0 black;
}
nav.sitenavigation a:focus {
 color: yellow;
 text-shadow: 1px -1px 0 black;
}
nav.sitenavigation a:active {
 position: relative;
 top: 1px;
 left: 1px;
}

/* body and page container */
body {
   font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   background-color: #faebbf;
}
.container {
   max-width: 800px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background-color: #6ac238;
   position: relative;
}
/* Skip Nav section */
p.skipnavigation {
 position: absolute;
 left: -10000px;
}
p.skipnavigation a:focus {
 color: black;
 background-color: white;
 position: relative;
 top: .4em;
 left: auto;
 right: .4em;
 z-index: 2;
}
/* print styles */
@media print {
   .container, h1, h2, header, header p, nav p, nav, div, article, p.sitenavigation, nav.sitenavigation, nav.sitenavigation a:visited , p.skipnavigation a:focus, nav.sitenavigation a:link  {
      color: black;
      background-color: white;
   }
}
@page {
   margin: 1in;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can not do it otherwise with pure css. There is other easier ways to make SCSS, the code is cleaner.

Another way, would you upload a specific file to the print medium, in this way, you can centralize all the styling for a certain type of screen, facilitating maintainability.

Something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="http://foo.com/mystyle.css" />
```

For more informations, [look here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Media_features).

I have helped in some way.

Comment: I suppose i didn't specify my intent, I was looking at it for sending it to a printer. The HTML is formatted in such a way that would not be useful when printed out.

Answer (score 0):

Stripping all formatting is probably not what you want - try it, but trust that it's going to look pretty weird. You might be better off stripping specific styles, like `* { background: none transparent; color: #000; }`, for starters. The `*` selector will target everything, so use carefully.

If you *really* want to remove every style, there's `* { all: unset }` or `* { all: initial }` - these have slightly different behaviors, but be aware, [browser support for `all` isn't perfect](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-all).

You could also look at the various css resets out there, which strip or normalize most styles.

Comment: I'm going to have to look over this in more detail when I have the time. At a glance this may be more useful, I did see that Safari and IE are not supported in this.